# fireEvent on SegmentedControlIOS

Tags: react-native, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library

I am using react-native-testing-library - https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/getting-started

I have a `<SegmentedControlIOS>` - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/segmentedcontrolios

I want to pres the first segment. I am doing this:

```
const testID = "SegmentedControl";
const stub = jest.fn();
const values = [{ label: "foo" }];
const { getByTestId } = render(
  <SegmentedControlIOS values={['foo', 'bar']} onChange={stub} testID={testID} />
);

expect(() => {
  getByTestId(testID);
}).not.toThrow();

fireEvent(getByTestId(testID), "change ", {
  nativeEvent: {
    value: values[0],
    selectedSegmentIndex: 0,
  },
});
```

However I get the error:

```
No handler function found for event: "change "
```

Screenshot below. Anyone know how to press different segments in `<SegmentedControlIOS>`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fireEvent(element: ReactTestInstance, eventName: string, ...data:
>   Array): void

The `change` function is located in the `fireEvent` object. Here's how to use it:

Version 5 or later:

```js
fireEvent.change(getByTestId(testID), { target: { value: values[0],selectedSegmentIndex: 0 } });
```

Version 5 or before:

```js
const input = getByTestId(testID);
  input.value = values[0];
  input.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
  fireEvent.change(input);
```

If you want to check the `onChange` function of `SegmentedControlIOS`,

using `fireEvent` with native events that aren't already aliased by the `fireEvent` api.

```js
// you can omit the `on` prefix
fireEvent(getByTestId(testID), 'onChange');
```

Comment: Thanks Hong, however I don't think this works with react-native. The `react-native-testing-library` doesn't even have `fireEvent.change`. :(

Comment: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library#complex-example You can see the use of this in this example. @Noitidart

Comment: It's not working :( `react-native-testing-library` doesn't have `change` method on `fireEvent`. I also tried `fireEvent(instantce, 'change', data)` but I get the error `No handler function found for event: "change "`. What does this error mean?

Comment: @Noitidart  Look at my answer. The second parameter is eventName. There is no change in the props you want to test.

Comment: Oh interesting thank you! I will try this in a couple hours and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

A solution was posted here, I didn't try it yet, but it looks more right I think - https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/220#issuecomment-541067962

```
import React from "react";
import { SegmentedControlIOS } from "react-native";
import { fireEvent, render } from "react-native-testing-library";

const testID = "SegmentedControl";
const stub = jest.fn();
const values = [{ label: "foo" }];
const { getByTestId } = render(
  <SegmentedControlIOS
    values={["foo", "bar"]}
    onChange={stub}
    testID={testID}
  />,
);
it("sends events", () => {
  fireEvent(getByTestId(testID), "onChange", {
    nativeEvent: {
      value: values[0],
      selectedSegmentIndex: 0,
    },
  });
});
```